# Determine whether a sorted array contain at least 4 distinct elements in O(log n) time

Tags: algorithms, binary-search

On one of my previous courseworks, I was faced with the following problem, which I think is unrealistic when using a direct / straightforward approach that usually algorithms have by leveraging certain data structures like dictionaries, etc.

> Design an O(log n) algorithm whose input is a sorted list A. The algorithm
> should return true if A contains at least 4 distinct elements. Otherwise
> the algorithm should return false.

My lecturer came up with the following solution:

```python
def ThreeDiff(A):
  if A[0]==A[len(A)-1]:
    return -1

  minind=0
  maxind=len(A)-1

  while maxind-mind>1:
    midind=int((minind+maxind)/2)
    if A[midind]>A[minind] and A[midind]<A[maxind]:
      return midind
    if A[midind]==A[minind]:
      minind=midind
    else:
     maxind=midind
  return -1

def FourDiff(A):
  midind=ThreeDiff(A)
  if midind==-1:
    return false
  return ThreeDiff(A[0:midind+1])!=- 1 or ThreeDiff(A[midind:len(A)]) != -1
```

Is there a cleaner or better way to solve this problem?

Comment: However due to how python's array slicing works, this piece of code will run much slower. Doing `A[0:midind+1]` will take up $O(n)$ time alone!

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. It would be better with additionnal arguments in `ThreeDiff` delimiting the bounds.

Comment: The entire solution is just a few lines. Looks pretty clean to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cleaner and better way to solve the problem.

```Python
# Return the smallest index where the element is bigger than `A[start_index]`.
# If `len(A)` is returned, no element is bigger than `A[start_index]`.
def next_bigger_element(start_index, A):
    lo, hi = start_index, len(A)
    while lo + 1 < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if A[mid] == A[start_index]:
            lo = mid
        else:
            hi = mid
    return hi


def distinct_elements_at_least(k, A):
    if len(A) == 0:
        return k <= 0
    index = 0
    count = 1
    # keep finding the next bigger element until `k` elements have
    # been found or we have reached the end of the array.
    while count < k and A[index] != A[-1]:
        index = next_bigger_element(index, A)
        count += 1
    return count >= k
```

To find whether `A` contains at least 4 distinct elements, just call `distinct_elements_at_least(4, A)`.

This program works correctly for any given number `k`. For example, it can be used to check whether `A` has 0 element  or whether `A` has 7 distinct elements. For any fixed `k`, it works in $O(\log n)$ time as at most `k` binary searches on an interval of size at most `n` are done.

---

If you do not mind `import bisect`, you may prefer the following shorter code, since method `next_bigger_element` is no longer needed.

```Python
from bisect import bisect_right

def distinct_elements_at_least(k, A):
    if len(A) == 0:
        return k <= 0
    index = 0
    count = 0
    while index < len(A) and count < k:
        count += 1
        index = bisect_right(A, A[index], index + 1)
    return count >= k
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I totally appreciate it. I have accepted this answer!